# Setting UL min-height depending on parent height

Tags: jquery, html, navigation, e-commerce, css

Basically we have a shop category navigation which goes into 3 levels. What we need to do it get it so that the height of the UL extends to be at least the height of its child.

So say for example **#nav ul** was 600px, **#nav ul ul** would automatically become at least 600px itself. However if **#nav ul ul ul** was 750px then it would need to be able to be that tall, rather than being restricted to 600px.

We can get it so that if the parent is 600px all children are set to .height of 600px, but how do you do this as min-height?

See link for example:

As you can see the 2nd level adjusts to the height of the parent but then the 3rd level is restricted to that length as the js sets the height, rather than min-height

Thanks,
Mike

Comment: You should set a jsfiddle to let us see what's going on

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/bzsM9/16/

Comment: hey if three of them gets equal? or parent ul remains the same but **ul ul** and **ul ul ul** both becomes same?

Comment: check it out man : http://jsfiddle.net/bzsM9/19/

Comment: Thanks for your help. We've reached a compromise on what we initially wanted thanks to you guys' input so thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Just use `.css('min-height', someHeight)` instead of `.height(someHeight)`

Comment: Yes the min-height was helpful (that was the obvious bit I was missing) - the issue now is that every ul adapts to the min-height of whichever is tallest. What it needs to do is: level 1 can be any height. Level 2 will always be at least the height of level 1. Level 3 only needs to be at least the height of its parent (at level 2). Very confusing I know!

Answer (score 0):

i can't understand what you want but i can do what i can do ;)

```
$(document).ready( function() {
var i1 = 600;
var i2 = $("#nav ul ul").height();
var i3 = $("#nav ul ul ul").height();
if(i2 >= i1) {
$("#nav ul ul").css({ 'min-height':'600px' });
}
if(i3 >= i1) {
$("#nav ul ul ul").css({ 'min-height':'600px' });
}
});
```

**No downvoting ah if it was wrong**

Comment: I have, see comment under his. Also more details under comment below

Answer (score 0):

Is it what you are looking for?
[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/bzsM9/17/)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('ul').hover(function(){
         $('ul').setAllToMaxHeight();
    });
});​
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't retrieve dimensions for hidden elements. The results will be height and width are zero. Instead of hiding them you can set the sub UL position offscreen using css like:

```
 ul ul {position: absolute; left: 80px; top: -999em}
 ul li:hover > ul {top:0;}
```

Since they are not hidden your `setAllToMaxHeight()` method works

DEMO :  http://jsfiddle.net/bzsM9/18/